# How to make HTTPs Request with Cookie in Android

Tags: java, android

What I need is = My App need to send a HTTPs Request with my Session Cookie and it needs to return the response to my TextView.

there are many answers around the internet for HTTP Request and i tried HTTP request and it gave me a different response. I cant find any answer for HTTPs Request, If anyone can help me then it would a great help for me.

I am trying this since 3days ago. My mind got frustrated.

I am new to Android and Java so if u would explain me with code it would be amazing!

My Thread Code when I tried HTTP Request :

```
Thread thread=new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                            URL request_url = new URL("http://ccsmash.space/CreditSystem/apis/credit6?lista=5159420147330524%7c06%7c2026%7c427&userid=&userAuth=2001710758");
                            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) request_url.openConnection();
                            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "loggedIn=1; PHPSESSID=e6e5805a8eb29f093d80476a608eb722");

                            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                            Log.i("RESULT", "Server responded with : " + responseCode);

                            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                                InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                                String content = convertInputStream(is, "UTF-8");
                                is.close();

                                tvcc.setText(content);
                                Log.i("RESULT",content);
                            }

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
```

My convertInputStream method code :

```
private String convertInputStream(InputStream is, String encoding) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is, encoding).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
}
```

My Output in Logcat was : I/RESULT: Server responded with : 301

Comment: Generally speaking, it should not matter if the request is made using http or https, since most web clients support both. Can you provide specific details about what is not working?

Comment: @MateiMacoveiciuc Actually if i use HTTP in the response i get 301 Document Moved Permanently

Comment: @MateiMacoveiciuc but when I try from php, I get proper response

Comment: Then the https connection is properly realized. Can you try it from a standard API tester, like Postman? Also please post your code.

Comment: @MateiMacoveiciuc i have edited the post with the code now.

Comment: And is your request working as expected in another client, like Postman? And on a side note, is there any reason why you're not using a web client such as Retrofit? That would save you from having to manually handle the connection and the input stream.

Comment: @MateiMacoveiciuc I don't know how to use postman, I just want to achieve my output so if anything can make it to achieve then I am ready to move my code to that. also I don't know how to use retrofit too.